# Grails hosting with Neo4j to read/write files

Tags: grails, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm developing a application which based on neo4j, the nature of neo4j is just plain files, so it needs to be able to write to local files. Google App Engine doesn't support writing to local files. I'm looking at Amazon S3 and EC2 right now. I just want to make sure that Amazone AWS supports read/write to local files.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Neo4j wiki](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_in_the_Cloud) has some information.

Answer (score 1):

There are also ready made [AMI's](http://jussiheinonen.blogspot.com/2011/05/neo4j-graph-database-server-image-in.html) for Neo4j-Server on all regions.

If you want to run embedded, just choose any linux and install the jvm on that one.

After that your Neo4j application should run just fine.